# Redirect after the registration

Tags: redirect

I have 2 registration pages, one for Korean, and one for English.
The Korean registration is okay. The page `/register` is redirect to `/checkout` page. (registration leads to subscription based) after the registration.

On the other hand, the English registration page /register-eng is supposed to redirect to `/checkout/?lang=en` page.
but after the registration, `/register-eng` also redirects to the same `/checkout` page.

Is there any `apply_filter` function to force redirect my English registration page to `/checkout/?lang=en` page?

Thanks in advance.

Test this code, but failed.

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'my_redirect_home' );
function my_redirect_home( $registration_redirect ) {
    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
    if( 'register-eng' === $post_slug ){
        $registration_redirect = 'http://example.com/checkout/?lang=en';
    }
    return $registration_redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPML you can use its built-in language condition statement.

```php
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en')
```

Therefore you can put your redirect function in this.

```php
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){
    // Your function
}
```